# Is garbage collection detrimental to the performance of this type of program

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm building a program that will live on an AWS EC2 instance (probably) be invoked periodically via a cron job. The program will 'crawl'/'poll' specific websites that we've partnered with and index/aggregate their content and update our database. I'm thinking java is a perfect fit for a language to program this application in. Some members of our engineering team are concerned about the performance detriment of java's garbage collection feature, and are suggesting using C++.

Are these valid concerns? This is an application that will be invoked possible once every 30 minutes via cron job, and as long as it finishes its task within that time frame the performance is acceptable I would assume. I'm not sure if garbage collection would be a performance issue, since I would assume the server will have plenty of memory and the actual act of tracking how many objects point to an area of memory and then declaring that memory free when it reaches 0 doesn't seem too detrimental to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, your concerns are most likely unfounded.

GC can be a concern, when dealing with large heaps & fractured memory (requires a stop the world collection) or medium lived objects that are promoted to old generation but then quickly de-referenced (requires excessive GC, but can be fixed by resizing ratio of new:old space).

A web crawler is very unlikely to fit either of the above two profiles - you probably don't need a massive old generation and should have relatively short lived objects (page representation in memory while you parse out data) and this will be efficiently dealt with in the young generation collector.

We have an in-house crawler (Java) that can happily handle 2 million pages per day, including some additional post-processing per page, on commodity hardware (2G RAM), the main constraint is bandwidth. GC is a non-issue.

As others have mentioned, GC is rarely an issue for throughput sensitive applications (such as a crawler) but it can (if one is not careful) be an issue  for latency sensitive apps (such as a trading platform).

Comment: +1 for "We have an in-house crawler": hard to argue with that kind of evidence.

Answer (score 11):

The typical concern C++ programmers have for GC is one of latency.  That is, as you run a program, periodic GCs interrupt the mutator and cause spikes in latency.  Back when I used to run Java web applications for a living, I had a couple customers who would see latency spikes in the logs and complain about it — and my job was to tune the GC to minimize the impact of those spikes.  There are some relatively complicated advances in GC over the years to make monstrous Java applications run with consistently low latency, and I'm impressed with the work of the engineers at Sun (now Oracle) who made that possible.

However, GC has always been very good at handling tasks with high throughput, where latency is not a concern.  This includes cron jobs.  Your engineers have unfounded concerns.

> Note: A simple experimental GC reduced the cost of memory allocation / freeing to less than two instructions on average, which improved throughput, but this design is fairly esoteric and requires a lot of memory, which you don't have on EC2.

The simplest GCs around offer a tradeoff between large heap (high latency, high throughput) and small heap (lower latency, lower throughput).  It takes some profiling to get it right for a particular application and workload, but these simple GCs are very forgiving in a large heap / high throughput / high latency configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Fetching and parsing websites will take way more time than the garbage collector, its impact will be probably neliglible. Moreover, the automatic memory management is often more efficient when dealing with a lot of small objects (such as strings) than a manual memory management via new/delete. Not talking about the fact that the garbage collected memory is easier to use.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have any hard numbers to back this up, but code that does a lot of small string manipulations (lots of small allocations and deallocations in a short period of time) should be **much faster** in a garbage-collected environment.

The reason is that modern GC's "re-pack" the heap on a regular basis, by moving objects from an "eden" space to survivor spaces and then to a tenured object heap, and modern GC's are heavily optimized for the case where many small objects are allocated and then deallocated quickly.

For example, constructing a new string in Java (on any modern JVM) is **as fast as a stack allocation** in C++.  By contrast, unless you're doing fancy string-pooling stuff in C++, you'll be really taxing your allocator with lots of small and quick allocations.

Plus, there are several other good reasons to consider Java for this sort of app: it has better out-of-the-box support for network protocols, which you'll need for fetching website data, and it is much more robust against the possibility of buffer overflows in the face of malicious content.

Answer (score 5):

Garbage collection (GC) is fundamentally a space-time tradeoff. The more memory you have, the less time your program will need to spend performing garbage collection. As long as you have a lot of memory available relative to the maximum live size (total memory in use), the main performance hit of GC -- whole-heap collections -- should be a rare event. Java's other advantages (notably robustness, security, portability, and an excellent networking library) make this a no-brainer.

For some hard data to share with your colleagues showing that GC performs as well as `malloc`/`free` with plenty of available RAM, see:

"*[**Quantifying the Performance of Garbage Collection vs. Explicit Memory Management**](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/gcvsmalloc.pdf)*", Matthew Hertz and Emery D. Berger, OOPSLA 2005.

> This paper provides empirical answers to an age-old question: is
>   garbage collection faster/slower/the same speed as malloc/free? We
>   introduce oracular memory management, an approach that lets us measure
>   unaltered Java programs as if they used malloc and free. The result: a
>   good GC can match the performance of a good allocator, but it takes 5X
>   more space. If physical memory is tight, however, conventional garbage
>   collectors suffer an order-of-magnitude performance penalty.

Paper: [PDF](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/gcvsmalloc.pdf)
Presentation slides: [PPT](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/presentations/oopsla2005-quantifyinggc.ppt), [PDF](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/presentations/oopsla2005-gcvsmalloc.pdf)